# How to force Facebook to display URL content?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

At the moment my facebook addon is able to post URLs from the app to user's wall. However, posted URL is posted as a simple URL (a link). It looks like this at the moment:

> I have posted a message and a http://www.site.com

How can I force Facebook to fetch and display the content of the URL and post it along the user's text? Something like this

[image]

I am posting messages as `String` and URL as `Uri`. The code is below.

```
private static final String MSG = "I have just posted a message and a link";
private static final String MSG2 = " to http://www.site.com";
private static final Uri MSG_URL = Uri.parse("http://www.site.com");
private void postMessageInThread() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    facebookConnector.postMessageOnWall(MSG + 
                            MSG2 + MSG_URL);
                    mFacebookHandler.post(mUpdateFacebookNotification);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error sending msg", ex);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: Post the URL using the `link` parameter, instead of having it just be part of the message. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#links

Comment: @CBroe Please add this as an answer as this is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post the URL using the `link` parameter, instead of having it just be part of the message.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#links